# python 3 urllib.request.urlopen not working in place of python 2 urllib2.urlopen

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, rest

I inherited some python 2 code that uses `urllib2.urlopen` to post some data to a local server, and I'd like to convert it to python 3. I initially tried the `requests` module, and when that didn't work I fell back to `urllib.request.urlopen`, since the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen) says

> urllib.request.urlopen() corresponds to the old `urllib2.urlopen`.

Both python 3 approaches are throwing the same exception, while the python 2 code works fine.

**working python 2 code:**

```
>>> request = urllib2.Request(url)
>>> request.add_data(data)
>>> response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
>>> response.read()
''
>>> response.close()
```

**python 3 equivalent**

```
>>> request = urllib.request.Request(url, data)
>>> response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
```

generates the following traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RemoteDisconnected                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-d5c6f6ac8b5c> in <module>()
----> 1 response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
    221     else:
    222         opener = _opener
--> 223     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    224
    225 def install_opener(opener):

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    524             req = meth(req)
    525
--> 526         response = self._open(req, data)
    527
    528         # post-process response

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in _open(self, req, data)
    542         protocol = req.type
    543         result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
--> 544                                   '_open', req)
    545         if result:
    546             return result

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    502         for handler in handlers:
    503             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
--> 504             result = func(*args)
    505             if result is not None:
    506                 return result

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in http_open(self, req)
   1344
   1345     def http_open(self, req):
-> 1346         return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
   1347
   1348     http_request = AbstractHTTPHandler.do_request_

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
   1319             except OSError as err: # timeout error
   1320                 raise URLError(err)
-> 1321             r = h.getresponse()
   1322         except:
   1323             h.close()

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in getresponse(self)
   1329         try:
   1330             try:
-> 1331                 response.begin()
   1332             except ConnectionError:
   1333                 self.close()

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in begin(self)
    295         # read until we get a non-100 response
    296         while True:
--> 297             version, status, reason = self._read_status()
    298             if status != CONTINUE:
    299                 break

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in _read_status(self)
    264             # Presumably, the server closed the connection before
    265             # sending a valid response.
--> 266             raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
    267                                      " response")
    268         try:

RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response
```

I'd really like to avoid converting my existing code to python 2 if at all possible. I don't have any control over how the server handles requests.

Comment: Use the requests module. Also, is this POST or GET? What kind of data are you trying to pass there?

Comment: the requests module throws the same underlying exception, as I mention at the top of the question. the data is a byte encoded string. it should be POST but I think that's being determined under the hood by the `urllib2` or `urllib.request` module

Comment: have you tried `requests.post(url, data=yourdata)` ?

Comment: yes I have, it throws the same underlying exception

Comment: to clarify when using requests the exception is: `ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))`

Comment: That is weird, if if works from python2, this error indicates that the connection was prematurely closed by the server

Comment: @barlaensdoonn have you tried looking at the requests with a tool such as wireshark, to see if they encode the data differently, or if perhaps urllib2 sets different headers?

Comment: @colde I originally got the data encoding by using wireshark, but I will take a look again to see about the headers

Comment: @barlaensdoonn right, if what it sent with the python 3 and python 3 approaches look identical in wireshark, then it should also work the same, unless something else is completely broken.

Comment: as far as I can tell the requests look identical after inspecting them with wireshark